# Identifying values that stick out

Tags: python

Given a dict:

```
data = {'18': [3.89, 1.28], '20': [1.39, 3.15], '15': [1.42, 3.10]}
```

I want to pick out items that clearly differ from the rest as in `18`. Ideally I would specify `ALLOWED_DISCREPANCY`, setting it to `0.5` for demo, a threshold which categorizes what does and does not stick out (compared to rest of values).

The `18` with its `3.89` is clearly off here because the majority has values around 1.4 (comparing either value from each list is enough to conclude) and the difference (`abs(3.89 - 1.4)`) is greater than `0.5` (max allowed).

Comment: Are all the lists *guaranteed* to have the same length?

Comment: yes, always 2-elem lists.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to find the values which are further away from the mean of all values than a specified threshold? And if so, do you only need the values or the dict keys where the values are stored, too?

Comment: It's exactly as you say. I needs the keys actually.

Comment: Do you really want to work with a hard-coded threshold or would you prefer to detect all statistical outliers?

Comment: Hard-coded is all I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the mean of the values.

```
>>> from numpy import mean
>>> data = {'18': [3.89, 1.28], '20': [1.39, 3.15], '15': [1.42, 3.10]}
>>> avg = mean([x for sublist in data.values() for x in sublist])
>>> avg
2.3716666666666666
```

Set the threshold and build a new dictionary which maps the original keys to a list of values that match your constraint. Here's two examples:

```
>>> thresh = 0.5
>>> {k:[x for x in v if abs(x-avg) > thresh] for k, v in data.items()}
{'18': [3.89, 1.28], '15': [1.42, 3.1], '20': [1.39, 3.15]}
>>>
>>> thresh = 1
>>> {k:[x for x in v if abs(x-avg) > thresh] for k, v in data.items()}
{'18': [3.89, 1.28], '15': [], '20': []}
```

edit: taking into account only one position

```
>>> pos = 0
>>> {k:v[pos] for k, v in data.items() if abs(v[pos]-avg) > thresh}
{'18': 3.89}
>>> 
>>> pos = 1
>>> {k:v[pos] for k, v in data.items() if abs(v[pos]-avg) > thresh}
{'18': 1.28}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've misguided you in the comments. When identyfing the outliers I take into account only one value from each list i.e `3.89, 1.39, 1.42` (items at position `[0]`) or `1.28, 3.15, 3.1` (items at position `[1]`) (does not matter if you take the items at pos[0] or at pos[1] but need to be consistent). Are you able to update the answer?

Comment: @rojas sure, I'll be able to fix it when I get home (few hours)

Comment: Thanks. Just to elaborate a bit: I think comparing to the mean won't really cut it (tried it prior to opening the thread) because the outlier will skew the mean every time. For example: `avg = np.mean([3.89, 1.39, 1.42]) #  2.23`, now hadn't the outlier been there, the mean would have been very different `1.405`.

Comment: @rojas you could only take values from certain quartiles of your data when computing the mean, or only values with a certain distance from the median or only values within 1,2,3,... standard deviations. As it stands, your question is now underspecified because you don't even know what you want. I would delete my answer, but accepted answers cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted a more statistical approach to finding outliers, you could do something like this:

```
data = {'18': [3.89, 1.28], '20': [1.39, 3.15], '15': [1.42, 3.10]}

avg = np.mean([x for sublist in data.values() for x in sublist])
stddev = np.std([x for sublist in data.values() for x in sublist])
```

For one standard deviation:

```
n_stddevs = 1

{k: [x for x in v if x  >= avg-stddev*n_stddevs and x <= avg+stddev*n_stddevs] for k, v in data.items()}

# {'15': [1.42, 3.1], '18': [], '20': [1.39, 3.15]}
```

For 2:

```
n_stddevs = 2

{k: [x for x in v if x  >= avg-stddev*n_stddevs and x <= avg+stddev*n_stddevs] for k, v in data.items()}

#{'15': [1.42, 3.1], '18': [3.89, 1.28], '20': [1.39, 3.15]}
```

For 0.5:

```
n_stddevs = 0.5

{k: [x for x in v if x  >= avg-stddev*n_stddevs and x <= avg+stddev*n_stddevs] for k, v in data.items()}

# {'15': [], '18': [], '20': []}
```